# DynamoDB data model secondary index search

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Folks,
  Given we have to store the following shopping cart data:

```
 userID1         ['itemID1','itemID2','itemID3']
 userID2         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID7']
 userID3         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID1']
```

We need to run the following queries:

- Give me all items (which is a list) for a specific user (easy).
- Give me all users which have `itemID3` (**precisely my question**).

How would you model this in DynamoDB?

Option 1, only have the Hash key? ie

```
    HashKey(users)  cartItems
    userID1         ['itemID1','itemID2','itemID3']
    userID2         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID7']
    userID3         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID1']
```

Option 2, Hash and Range keys?

```
    HashKey(users)  RangeKey(cartItems)
    userID1         ['itemID1','itemID2','itemID3']
    userID2         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID7']
    userID3         ['itemID3','itemID2','itemID1']
```

But it seems that range keys can only be strings, numbers, or binary...

Should this be solved by having 2 tables?  How would you model them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rule 1: The range keys in DynamoDB table must be scalar, and that's why the type must be *strings*, *numbers*, *boolean* or *binaries*. You can't take a *list*, *set*, or a *map* type.

Rule 2: You cannot (currently) create a secondary index off of a nested attribute. From the [*Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB* documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html). That means, you can not index the cartItems since it's not a top level JSON attribute. You *may* need another table for this.

So, the simple answer to your question is another question: **how do you use your data?**

---

If you query the users with input item (say `itemID3` in your case) infrequently, perhaps a `Scan` operation with [filter expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan) will work just fine. To model your data, you may use the user id as the `HASH` key and cartItems as the string set (`SS` type) attribute. For queries, you need to provide a `filter expression` for the `Scan` operation like this:

```
contains(cartItems, :expectedItem)
```

and, provide the value `itemID3` for the placeholder `:expectedItem` in parameter `valueMap`.

If you run many queries like this frequently, perhaps you can create another table taking the item id as the `HASH` key, and set of users having that item as the string set attribute. In this case, the 2nd query in your question turns out to be the 1st query in the other table.

Be aware of that, you need to maintain the data at two tables for each CRUD action, which may be trivial with [DynamoDB Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html).